# Normalize a vector based on two other values

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
  Type=rep(LETTERS[1:6],3),
  Level=rep(1:3,each=6),
  Value=1:18)
```

I'd like to add 2 columns,

- add 'r1', the ratio of Value to the Type A Value for the same Level
- add 'r2', the ratio of Value to the Level 1 Value of the same Type

to end up with

```
> df
   Type Level Value       r1   r2
1     A     1     1 1.000000  1.0
2     B     1     2 2.000000  1.0
3     C     1     3 3.000000  1.0
4     D     1     4 4.000000  1.0
5     E     1     5 5.000000  1.0
6     F     1     6 6.000000  1.0
7     A     2     7 1.000000  7.0
8     B     2     8 1.142857  4.0
9     C     2     9 1.285714  3.0
10    D     2    10 1.428571  2.5
11    E     2    11 1.571429  2.2
12    F     2    12 1.714286  2.0
13    A     3    13 1.000000 13.0
14    B     3    14 1.076923  7.0
15    C     3    15 1.153846  5.0
16    D     3    16 1.230769  4.0
17    E     3    17 1.307692  3.4
18    F     3    18 1.384615  3.0
```

I tried a few `apply` type approaches, but couldn't get it.  I ended up with a double `for` loop:

```
for(i in unique(df$Type)) {
  for(j in unique(df$Level)) {
    df$r1[df$Level==j & df$Type==i] <- df$Value[df$Level==j & df$Type==i]/df$Value[df$Level==j & df$Type=="A"]
    df$r2[df$Level==j & df$Type==i] <- df$Value[df$Level==j & df$Type==i]/df$Value[df$Level==1 & df$Type==i]
  }
}
```

This isn't too bad, but I'm wondering if there is a split-apply-combine approach that would do it, maybe with something in `plyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you suggested a `plyr` solution:

```
df <- ddply(df, .(Level), transform, r1 = Value / Value[Type == "A"])
df <- ddply(df, .(Type),  transform, r2 = Value / Value[Level == 1])
```

which I think reads nicely.

Comment: Unless ddply is doing something that I don't understand (which is quite possible), it looks like you're doing the vector operation df$Value/df$Value[df$Type=="A"].  That recycles the elements of the three "A" values in the wrong order.  Thus the call to rep() in my answer.

Comment: No, it is doing the right thing. The second argument to `ddply` is a variable used for grouping the data, so there is e.g. a single `Type == "A"` for each `Level` and not three like you suggest. You could have just run my solution to check that it is correct and matches your result. It is also more general as it does not rely on the assumption you make that groups must have the same length.

Comment: Indeed.  I need to study plyr.  Interesting that it reorders the rows of the data frame.

Comment: Yes, this is just the kind of thing I was looking for.  I hadn't thought about using `transform` for the function. Thank you.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg and also interesting that if the two statements are run in reverse order, the data frame is left in the original order.  I guess the recombining in each statement is consistent with how it was split.

Answer (score 1):

Create vectors first, then cbind them to the data frame:

```
 r1 <- df$Value / df$Value[rep(df$Value[df$Type=='A'], each=length(levels(df$Type)))]
 r2 <- df$Value / df$Value[seq_along(levels(df$Type))]
```

This assumes that the "Types" are repeated for each "Level", as in your example.

Here is the appropriate cbind() call:

```
cbind(df, r1, r2)
```